# Resources needed to start windows programming with C++CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I'm already new in **C++CLI** , although I have been working on VB and C++ for a long time , but I need to start a projects on CLI using it's visual screens and easy codes (just in windows) , But I can't find any good Resource or book to start **windows programming** (I mean codes that you can give it to buttons or texts without using c++ classes) ,

**Can I find any of them ?**

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you 3 books ( I used them ):

1. Foundations of C++/CLI The Visual C++ Language for.NET 3.5
2. Pro Visual C++/CLI and the .NET 3.5 Platform
3. C++/CLI in Action

They are in order of difficulty. 
The first and the 2nd are introductory and advance respectively.
The 3rd is great for advanced topics, like interop, mixed-mode coding etc..

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you have done in your work with C++ without classes, it is C with classes :).  If you want to write Windows Program in C, Programming Windows, 5th Edition written by Charles Petzold could be a good start. Then you can decide which managed GUI to learn. Winform is mature with no future planned beyond .Net 4.0, while WPF is growing and is the main focus of Microsoft.